# How to get date of an event by web scraping in python(Beautiful Soup)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

url = 'https://www.premierleague.com/match/59001'

I want to get the date of this match but I can't.
This is what I tried

```
soup.select('div.matchInfo div.matchDate.renderMatchDateContainer')[0].text
```

Comment: please see [ask] a question and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at the page source, all the data is in the json format in the `div` tag.

```
import json, requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.premierleague.com/match/59001'

res = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")

data = json.loads(soup.find("div", class_="mcTabsContainer")["data-fixture"])

print(data)
```

Output:

```
{"gameweek":{"id":5674,"compSeason":{"label":"2020/21","competition":{"abbreviation":"EN_PR","description":"Premier League","level":"SEN","source":"","id":1,"altIds":{"opta":"8"}},"id":363},"gameweek":11,"competitionPhase":{"id":1322,"type":"L","gameweekRange":[1,38]}},"kickoff":{"completeness":3,"millis":1607180400000,"label":"Sat 5 Dec 2020, 15:00 GMT"},"provisionalKickoff":{"completeness":3,"millis":1607180400000,"label":"Sat 5 Dec 2020, 15:00 GMT"},"teams":[{"team":{"name":"Manchester City","club":{"name":"Manchester City","shortName":"Man City","abbr":"MCI","id":11},"teamType":"FIRST","shortName":"Man City","id":11,"altIds":{"opta":"t43"}},"score":2},{"team":{"name":"Fulham","club":{"name":"Fulham","shortName":"Fulham","abbr":"FUL","id":34},"teamType":"FIRST","shortName":"Fulham","id":34,"altIds":{"opta":"t54"}},"score":0}],"replay":false,"ground":{"name":"Etihad Stadium","city":"Manchester","source":"OPTA","id":457},"neutralGround":false,"status":"C","phase":"F","outcome":"H","clock":{"secs":5580,"label":"90 +3\\u002700"},"fixtureType":"REGULAR","extraTime":false,"shootout":false,"matchOfficials":[{"matchOfficialId":70528,"role":"MAIN","birth":{},"name":{"display":"Jonathan Moss","first":"Jonathan","last":"Moss"},"id":16964},{"matchOfficialId":70529,"role":"LINESMAN_1","birth":{},"name":{"display":"Marc Perry","first":"Marc","last":"Perry"},"id":17001},{"matchOfficialId":70530,"role":"LINESMAN_2","birth":{},"name":{"display":"Dan Robathan","first":"Dan","last":"Robathan"},"id":17549},{"matchOfficialId":70531,"role":"FOURTH_OFFICIAL","birth":{},"name":{"display":"Darren Bond","first":"Darren","last":"Bond"},"id":17010},{"matchOfficialId":70532,"role":"VAR","birth":{},"name":{"display":"Graham Scott","first":"Graham","last":"Scott"},"id":16989},{"matchOfficialId":70533,"role":"ASSISTANT_VAR","birth":{},"name":{"display":"Matt Wilkes","first":"Matt","last":"Wilkes"},"id":16976}],"halfTimeScore":{"homeScore":2,"awayScore":0},"teamLists":[{"teamId":11,"lineup":[{"matchPosition":"M","matchShirtNumber":16,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"M","shirtNum":16,"positionInfo":"Centre Central Midfielder"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"ES","country":"Spain","demonym":"Spanish"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":835401600000,"label":"22 June 1996"},"country":{"isoCode":"ES","country":"Spain","demonym":"Spanish"},"place":"Madrid"},"age":"24 years 166 days","name":{"display":"Rodrigo","first":"Rodrigo","last":"Hernández Cascante"},"id":16286,"altIds":{"opta":"p220566"}},{"matchPosition":"D","matchShirtNumber":5,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"D","shirtNum":5,"positionInfo":"Centre Central Defender"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"GB-ENG","country":"England","demonym":"English"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":770083200000,"label":"28 May 1994"},"country":{"isoCode":"GB-ENG","country":"England","demonym":"English"},"place":"Hemsworth"},"age":"26 years 191 days","name":{"display":"John Stones","first":"John","last":"Stones"},"id":4505,"altIds":{"opta":"p97299"}},{"matchPosition":"M","matchShirtNumber":8,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"M","shirtNum":8,"positionInfo":"Centre Central Midfielder"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"DE","country":"Germany","demonym":"German"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":656726400000,"label":"24 October 1990"},"country":{"isoCode":"DE","country":"Germany","demonym":"German"},"place":"Gelsenkirchen"},"age":"30 years 42 days","name":{"display":"Ilkay Gündogan","first":"Ilkay","last":"Gündogan"},"id":5101,"altIds":{"opta":"p59859"}},{"matchPosition":"D","matchShirtNumber":22,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"D","shirtNum":22,"positionInfo":"Left Full Back"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"FR","country":"France","demonym":"French"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":774403200000,"label":"17 July 1994"},"country":{"isoCode":"FR","country":"France","demonym":"French"},"place":"Longjumeau"},"age":"26 years 141 days","name":{"display":"Benjamin Mendy","first":"Benjamin","last":"Mendy"},"id":5575,"altIds":{"opta":"p102826"}},{"matchPosition":"F","matchShirtNumber":9,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"F","shirtNum":9,"positionInfo":"Left/Centre/Right Second Striker"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"BR","country":"Brazil","demonym":"Brazilian"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":860025600000,"label":"3 April 1997"},"country":{"isoCode":"BR","country":"Brazil","demonym":"Brazilian"},"place":"São Paulo"},"age":"23 years 246 days","name":{"display":"Gabriel Jesus","first":"Gabriel Fernando","last":"de Jesus"},"id":19680,"altIds":{"opta":"p205651"}},{"matchPosition":"G","matchShirtNumber":31,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"G","shirtNum":31,"positionInfo":"Goalkeeper"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"BR","country":"Brazil","demonym":"Brazilian"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":745545600000,"label":"17 August 1993"},"country":{"isoCode":"BR","country":"Brazil","demonym":"Brazilian"},"place":"Osasco"},"age":"27 years 110 days","name":{"display":"Ederson","first":"Ederson","last":"Santana de Moraes"},"id":12707,"altIds":{"opta":"p121160"}},{"matchPosition":"M","matchShirtNumber":17,"captain":true,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"M","shirtNum":17,"positionInfo":"Left/Centre/Right Attacking Midfielder"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"BE","country":"Belgium","demonym":"Belgian"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":678067200000,"label":"28 June 1991"},"country":{"isoCode":"BE","country":"Belgium","demonym":"Belgian"},"place":"Drongen"},"age":"29 years 160 days","name":{"display":"Kevin De Bruyne","first":"Kevin","last":"De Bruyne"},"id":4288,"altIds":{"opta":"p61366"}},{"matchPosition":"D","matchShirtNumber":27,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"D","shirtNum":27,"positionInfo":"Right Full Back"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"PT","country":"Portugal","demonym":"Portugese"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":769996800000,"label":"27 May 1994"},"country":{"isoCode":"PT","country":"Portugal","demonym":"Portugese"},"place":"Barreiro"},"age":"26 years 192 days","name":{"display":"João Cancelo","first":"João Pedro","last":"Cavaco Cancelo"},"id":5051,"altIds":{"opta":"p121145"}},{"matchPosition":"M","matchShirtNumber":26,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"F","shirtNum":26,"positionInfo":"Left/Right Winger"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"DZ","country":"Algeria","demonym":"Algerian"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":667094400000,"label":"21 February 1991"},"country":{"isoCode":"FR","country":"France","demonym":"French"},"place":"Sarcelles"},"age":"29 years 288 days","name":{"display":"Riyad Mahrez","first":"Riyad","last":"Mahrez"},"id":8983,"altIds":{"opta":"p103025"}},{"matchPosition":"M","matchShirtNumber":7,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"F","shirtNum":7,"positionInfo":"Left/Centre/Right Second Striker"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"GB-ENG","country":"England","demonym":"English"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":786844800000,"label":"8 December 1994"},"country":{"isoCode":"JM","country":"Jamaica","demonym":"Jamaican"},"place":"Kingston"},"age":"25 years 363 days","name":{"display":"Raheem Sterling","first":"Raheem","middle":"Shaquille","last":"Sterling"},"id":4316,"altIds":{"opta":"p103955"}},{"matchPosition":"D","matchShirtNumber":3,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"D","shirtNum":3,"positionInfo":"Centre Central Defender"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"PT","country":"Portugal","demonym":"Portugese"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":863568000000,"label":"14 May 1997"},"country":{"isoCode":"PT","country":"Portugal","demonym":"Portugese"},"place":"Amadora"},"age":"23 years 205 days","name":{"display":"Rúben Dias","first":"Rúben Santos","last":"Gato Alves Dias"},"id":16431,"altIds":{"opta":"p171314"}}],"substitutes":[{"matchPosition":"M","matchShirtNumber":25,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"M","shirtNum":25,"positionInfo":"Centre Defensive Midfielder"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"BR","country":"Brazil","demonym":"Brazilian"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":484012800000,"label":"4 May 1985"},"country":{"isoCode":"BR","country":"Brazil","demonym":"Brazilian"},"place":"Londrina"},"age":"35 years 215 days","name":{"display":"Fernandinho","first":"Fernando","last":"Luiz Rosa"},"id":4804,"altIds":{"opta":"p27789"}},{"matchPosition":"D","matchShirtNumber":50,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"D","shirtNum":50,"positionInfo":"Centre Central Defender"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"ES","country":"Spain","demonym":"Spanish"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":978998400000,"label":"9 January 2001"},"country":{"isoCode":"ES","country":"Spain","demonym":"Spanish"}},"age":"19 years 331 days","name":{"display":"Eric García","first":"Eric","last":"García"},"id":24635,"altIds":{"opta":"p432656"}},{"matchPosition":"M","matchShirtNumber":20,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"M","shirtNum":20,"positionInfo":"Left/Centre Attacking Midfielder"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"PT","country":"Portugal","demonym":"Portugese"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":776476800000,"label":"10 August 1994"},"country":{"isoCode":"PT","country":"Portugal","demonym":"Portugese"},"place":"Lisbon"},"age":"26 years 117 days","name":{"display":"Bernardo Silva","first":"Bernardo Mota","last":"Veiga de Carvalho e Silva"},"id":5067,"altIds":{"opta":"p165809"}},{"matchPosition":"F","matchShirtNumber":21,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"F","shirtNum":21,"positionInfo":"Right Central Midfielder"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"ES","country":"Spain","demonym":"Spanish"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":951782400000,"label":"29 February 2000"},"country":{"isoCode":"ES","country":"Spain","demonym":"Spanish"},"place":"Foios"},"age":"20 years 280 days","name":{"display":"Ferran Torres","first":"Ferran","last":"Torres"},"id":43098,"altIds":{"opta":"p224444"}},{"matchPosition":"D","matchShirtNumber":14,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"D","shirtNum":14,"positionInfo":"Centre Central Defender"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"FR","country":"France","demonym":"French"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":769996800000,"label":"27 May 1994"},"country":{"isoCode":"FR","country":"France","demonym":"French"},"place":"Agen"},"age":"26 years 192 days","name":{"display":"Aymeric Laporte","first":"Aymeric","last":"Laporte"},"id":11044,"altIds":{"opta":"p146941"}},{"matchPosition":"M","matchShirtNumber":47,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"M","shirtNum":47,"positionInfo":"Centre/Right Attacking Midfielder"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"GB-ENG","country":"England","demonym":"English"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":959472000000,"label":"28 May 2000"},"country":{"isoCode":"GB-ENG","country":"England","demonym":"English"}},"age":"20 years 191 days","name":{"display":"Phil Foden","first":"Phil","last":"Foden"},"id":14805,"altIds":{"opta":"p209244"}},{"matchPosition":"G","matchShirtNumber":13,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"G","shirtNum":13,"positionInfo":"Goalkeeper"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"US","country":"United States","demonym":"American"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":796780800000,"label":"2 April 1995"},"country":{"isoCode":"US","country":"United States","demonym":"American"},"place":"Coatesville"},"age":"25 years 247 days","name":{"display":"Zack Steffen","first":"Zack","last":"Steffen"},"id":54392,"altIds":{"opta":"p164484"}}],"formation":{"label":"4-2-3-1","players":[[12707],[5051,4505,16431,5575],[16286,5101],[8983,4288,4316],[19680]]}},{"teamId":34,"lineup":[{"matchPosition":"M","matchShirtNumber":33,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"D","shirtNum":33,"positionInfo":"Left Full Back"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"US","country":"United States","demonym":"American"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":870998400000,"label":"8 August 1997"},"country":{"isoCode":"GB-ENG","country":"England","demonym":"English"},"place":"Milton Keynes"},"age":"23 years 119 days","name":{"display":"Antonee Robinson","first":"Antonee","last":"Robinson"},"id":14624,"altIds":{"opta":"p169528"}},{"matchPosition":"D","matchShirtNumber":16,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"D","shirtNum":16,"positionInfo":"Centre Central Defender"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"GB-ENG","country":"England","demonym":"English"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":875059200000,"label":"24 September 1997"},"country":{"isoCode":"GB-ENG","country":"England","demonym":"English"}},"age":"23 years 72 days","name":{"display":"Tosin Adarabioyo","first":"Tosin","last":"Adarabioyo"},"id":13549,"altIds":{"opta":"p109646"}},{"matchPosition":"F","matchShirtNumber":19,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"F","shirtNum":19,"positionInfo":"Left/Right Winger","loan":true},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"GB-ENG","country":"England","demonym":"English"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":877305600000,"label":"20 October 1997"},"country":{"isoCode":"GB-ENG","country":"England","demonym":"English"},"place":"London"},"age":"23 years 46 days","name":{"display":"Ademola Lookman","first":"Ademola","last":"Lookman"},"id":13278,"altIds":{"opta":"p219352"}},{"matchPosition":"F","matchShirtNumber":15,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"M","shirtNum":15,"positionInfo":"Centre Attacking Midfielder","loan":true},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"GB-ENG","country":"England","demonym":"English"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":822355200000,"label":"23 January 1996"},"country":{"isoCode":"GB-ENG","country":"England","demonym":"English"},"place":"London"},"age":"24 years 317 days","name":{"display":"Ruben Loftus-Cheek","first":"Ruben","last":"Loftus-Cheek"},"id":5179,"altIds":{"opta":"p126187"}},{"matchPosition":"M","matchShirtNumber":21,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"M","shirtNum":21,"positionInfo":"Centre Central Midfielder"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"GB-ENG","country":"England","demonym":"English"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":791164800000,"label":"27 January 1995"},"country":{"isoCode":"GB-ENG","country":"England","demonym":"English"}},"age":"25 years 313 days","name":{"display":"Harrison Reed","first":"Harrison","middle":"James","last":"Reed"},"id":4818,"altIds":{"opta":"p153366"}},{"matchPosition":"F","matchShirtNumber":17,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"F","shirtNum":17,"positionInfo":"Left/Right Winger"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"PT","country":"Portugal","demonym":"Portugese"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":750902400000,"label":"18 October 1993"},"country":{"isoCode":"PT","country":"Portugal","demonym":"Portugese"}},"age":"27 years 48 days","name":{"display":"Ivan Cavaleiro","first":"Ivan","last":"Cavaleiro"},"id":5079,"altIds":{"opta":"p166324"}},{"matchPosition":"M","matchShirtNumber":29,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"M","shirtNum":29,"positionInfo":"Centre Central Midfielder"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"CM","country":"Cameroon","demonym":"Cameroonian"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":816480000000,"label":"16 November 1995"},"country":{"isoCode":"CM","country":"Cameroon","demonym":"Cameroonian"},"place":"Yaoundé"},"age":"25 years 19 days","name":{"display":"André-Frank Zambo Anguissa","first":"André-Frank","last":"Zambo Anguissa"},"id":32162,"altIds":{"opta":"p203325"}},{"matchPosition":"M","matchShirtNumber":14,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"F","shirtNum":14,"positionInfo":"Centre Striker"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"JM","country":"Jamaica","demonym":"Jamaican"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":728611200000,"label":"2 February 1993"},"country":{"isoCode":"GB-ENG","country":"England","demonym":"English"},"place":"Bristol"},"age":"27 years 307 days","name":{"display":"Bobby De Cordova-Reid","first":"Bobby","last":"De Cordova-Reid"},"id":8192,"altIds":{"opta":"p96994"}},{"matchPosition":"G","matchShirtNumber":1,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"G","shirtNum":1,"positionInfo":"Goalkeeper","loan":true},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"FR","country":"France","demonym":"French"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":730771200000,"label":"27 February 1993"},"country":{"isoCode":"FR","country":"France","demonym":"French"},"place":"Paris"},"age":"27 years 282 days","name":{"display":"Alphonse Areola","first":"Alphonse","last":"Areola"},"id":5748,"altIds":{"opta":"p84182"}},{"matchPosition":"D","matchShirtNumber":34,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"D","shirtNum":34,"positionInfo":"Right Full Back","loan":true},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"NG","country":"Nigeria","demonym":"Nigerian"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":844732800000,"label":"8 October 1996"},"country":{"isoCode":"GB-ENG","country":"England","demonym":"English"},"place":"Southwark"},"age":"24 years 58 days","name":{"display":"Ola Aina","first":"Ola","last":"Aina"},"id":10439,"altIds":{"opta":"p159506"}},{"matchPosition":"D","matchShirtNumber":5,"captain":true,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"D","shirtNum":5,"positionInfo":"Centre Central Defender","loan":true},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"DK","country":"Denmark"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":833500800000,"label":"31 May 1996"},"country":{"isoCode":"DK","country":"Denmark"},"place":"Frederiksberg"},"age":"24 years 188 days","name":{"display":"Joachim Andersen","first":"Joachim","last":"Andersen"},"id":26151,"altIds":{"opta":"p174874"}}],"substitutes":[{"matchPosition":"M","matchShirtNumber":18,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"M","shirtNum":18,"positionInfo":"Centre Central Midfielder","loan":true},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"GA","country":"Gabon","demonym":"Gabonese"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":746841600000,"label":"1 September 1993"},"country":{"isoCode":"GA","country":"Gabon","demonym":"Gabonese"},"place":"Libreville"},"age":"27 years 95 days","name":{"display":"Mario Lemina","first":"Mario","last":"Lemina"},"id":5583,"altIds":{"opta":"p151086"}},{"matchPosition":"D","matchShirtNumber":13,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"D","shirtNum":13,"positionInfo":"Left/Centre Central Defender"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"US","country":"United States","demonym":"American"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":560390400000,"label":"5 October 1987"},"country":{"isoCode":"US","country":"United States","demonym":"American"},"place":"St. Louis"},"age":"33 years 61 days","name":{"display":"Tim Ream","first":"Tim","middle":"Michael","last":"Ream"},"id":4276,"altIds":{"opta":"p82514"}},{"matchPosition":"M","matchShirtNumber":10,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"M","shirtNum":10,"positionInfo":"Left/Centre/Right Attacking Midfielder"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"GB-SCT","country":"Scotland","demonym":"Scottish"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":664329600000,"label":"20 January 1991"},"country":{"isoCode":"GB-ENG","country":"England","demonym":"English"}},"age":"29 years 320 days","name":{"display":"Tom Cairney","first":"Tom","last":"Cairney"},"id":3894,"altIds":{"opta":"p76357"}},{"matchPosition":"G","matchShirtNumber":12,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"G","shirtNum":12,"positionInfo":"Goalkeeper"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"SK","country":"Slovakia","demonym":"Slovak"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":850435200000,"label":"13 December 1996"},"country":{"isoCode":"SK","country":"Slovakia","demonym":"Slovak"}},"age":"23 years 358 days","name":{"display":"Marek Rodák","first":"Marek","last":"Rodák"},"id":10727,"altIds":{"opta":"p155529"}},{"matchPosition":"F","matchShirtNumber":47,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"F","shirtNum":47,"positionInfo":"Centre Striker"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"FR","country":"France","demonym":"French"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":794534400000,"label":"7 March 1995"},"country":{"isoCode":"FR","country":"France","demonym":"French"}},"age":"25 years 273 days","name":{"display":"Aboubakar Kamara","first":"Aboubakar","last":"Kamara"},"id":11267,"altIds":{"opta":"p197030"}},{"matchPosition":"D","matchShirtNumber":23,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"D","shirtNum":23,"positionInfo":"Left Full Back"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"GB-ENG","country":"England","demonym":"English"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":748224000000,"label":"17 September 1993"},"country":{"isoCode":"GB-ENG","country":"England","demonym":"English"}},"age":"27 years 79 days","name":{"display":"Joe Bryan","first":"Joe","middle":"Edward","last":"Bryan"},"id":8185,"altIds":{"opta":"p101105"}},{"matchPosition":"F","matchShirtNumber":9,"captain":false,"playerId":0,"info":{"position":"F","shirtNum":9,"positionInfo":"Centre Striker"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"RS","country":"Serbia","demonym":"Serbian"},"birth":{"date":{"millis":779673600000,"label":"16 September 1994"},"country":{"isoCode":"YU","country":"Yugoslavia","demonym":"Yugoslavian"},"place":"Smederevo"},"age":"26 years 80 days","name":{"display":"Aleksandar Mitrovic","first":"Aleksandar","last":"Mitrovic"},"id":5879,"altIds":{"opta":"p128389"}}],"formation":{"label":"3-4-1-2","players":[[5748],[10439,26151,13549],[8192,32162,4818,14624],[5179],[13278,5079]]}}],"events":[{"clock":{"secs":0,"label":"00\\u002700"},"phase":"1","type":"PS","time":{"millis":1607180466000,"label":"5 December 2020, 15:01"},"score":{"homeScore":0,"awayScore":0}},{"id":94256,"personId":4316,"teamId":11,"assistId":4288,"clock":{"secs":300,"label":"05\\u002700"},"phase":"1","type":"G","description":"G","time":{"millis":1607180766000,"label":"5 December 2020, 15:06"},"score":{"homeScore":1,"awayScore":0}},{"id":94287,"personId":4288,"teamId":11,"clock":{"secs":1560,"label":"26\\u002700"},"phase":"1","type":"P","description":"P","time":{"millis":1607182026000,"label":"5 December 2020, 15:27"},"score":{"homeScore":2,"awayScore":0}},{"clock":{"secs":2820,"label":"45 +2\\u002700"},"phase":"1","type":"PE","time":{"millis":1607183231000,"label":"5 December 2020, 15:47"},"score":{"homeScore":2,"awayScore":0}},{"clock":{"secs":2700,"label":"45\\u002700"},"phase":"2","type":"PS","time":{"millis":1607184192000,"label":"5 December 2020, 16:03"},"score":{"homeScore":2,"awayScore":0}},{"id":181228,"personId":5583,"teamId":34,"clock":{"secs":4080,"label":"68\\u002700"},"phase":"2","type":"S","description":"ON","time":{"millis":1607185572000,"label":"5 December 2020, 16:26"},"score":{"homeScore":2,"awayScore":0}},{"id":181228,"personId":4818,"teamId":34,"clock":{"secs":4080,"label":"68\\u002700"},"phase":"2","type":"S","description":"OFF","time":{"millis":1607185572000,"label":"5 December 2020, 16:26"},"score":{"homeScore":2,"awayScore":0}},{"id":181243,"personId":11267,"teamId":34,"clock":{"secs":4320,"label":"72\\u002700"},"phase":"2","type":"S","description":"ON","time":{"millis":1607185812000,"label":"5 December 2020, 16:30"},"score":{"homeScore":2,"awayScore":0}},{"id":181243,"personId":8192,"teamId":34,"clock":{"secs":4320,"label":"72\\u002700"},"phase":"2","type":"S","description":"OFF","time":{"millis":1607185812000,"label":"5 December 2020, 16:30"},"score":{"homeScore":2,"awayScore":0}},{"id":181342,"personId":3894,"teamId":34,"clock":{"secs":4980,"label":"83\\u002700"},"phase":"2","type":"S","description":"ON","time":{"millis":1607186472000,"label":"5 December 2020, 16:41"},"score":{"homeScore":2,"awayScore":0}},{"id":181342,"personId":5179,"teamId":34,"clock":{"secs":4980,"label":"83\\u002700"},"phase":"2","type":"S","description":"OFF","time":{"millis":1607186472000,"label":"5 December 2020, 16:41"},"score":{"homeScore":2,"awayScore":0}},{"clock":{"secs":5580,"label":"90 +3\\u002700"},"phase":"2","type":"PE","time":{"millis":1607187033000,"label":"5 December 2020, 16:50"},"score":{"homeScore":2,"awayScore":0}}],"penaltyShootouts":[],"behindClosedDoors":true,"id":59001,"altIds":{"opta":"g2128391"},"metadata":{}}
```

You can easily parse the above json to get the date

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver



url = 'https://www.premierleague.com/match/59001'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
date =driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainContent"]/div/section[2]/div[2]/section/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]')
print(date.text)
```

Output:-

```
Sat 5 Dec 2020
```